# How to configure network in UBUNTU server VM

Tags: ubuntu, networking, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I have Ubuntu latest server edition installed as VM on Hyper-V.

I get the command line, but need to install GUI desktop for which i need to have network available on ubuntu.

From the Hyper-V VM console, it shows that my Virtual network is configured for the VM, but from LinuxVM cmd-line unable to ping.

I have 1 NIC with LAN and static IPs available on the Host Windows 2008 R2 Server.

My question is how to configure network (LAN or static IP) on Ubuntu VM ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For static IP, add to `/etc/network/interfaces` something like

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.217
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: Ok cool. I tried to open this file in vi. its weird, unable to edit, or give space delete characters. its making me nuts. I am able to type all characters on cmdline, so its no probs with keyboard (was detected correctly as us)

Comment: Are you editing it as root or via `sudo`? Or maybe you're not familiar with `vi`? You should press `i` to enable editing

Comment: ok, i did without sudo. even after pressing 'i' cannot use SPACE key. i have some exp. with vi in past. it is looking weird here.

Comment: Try using nano or pico, they are less picky :)